# Does SQLite use indexes I create when joining two views?

Tags: sqlite, spatialite

I want to use an index to speed up a left join of two SQLite views. However, it does not seem to use the index.

I have a SpatiaLite spatial table called RoadsPolyline. I add an index with

```
create index idx_RoadNames on
RoadsPolyline(RoadName)
```

I then create a very simple view

```
CREATE VIEW test as
select *
from RoadsPolyline
```

And when I query

```
explain query plan
select *
from test as t1
left join test as t2 on t1.RoadName = t2.RoadName
```

I get (detail column only):

```
SCAN TABLE RoadsPolyline
SCAN TABLE RoadsPolyline
SEARCH SUBQUERY 1 AS t2 USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (RoadName=?)
```

Most interestingly, when I remove the 'left' before join and make it an inner join, I get:

```
SCAN TABLE RoadsPolyline
SEARCH TABLE RoadsPolyline USING INDEX idx_RoadNames (RoadName=?)
```

So it is using the index for inner join, but not left join. However, I need to use left join for my more complex queries.

I am using SpatiaLite 4.3.0a, SQLite version 3.8.11.1.

Comment: Looks good to me, maybe a bug in SQLite?

Comment: Do you really need to use `SELECT *` here?  If not, then which columns do you actually need to select?

Comment: First thing to do is upgrade from that ancient version of sqlite and see if a newer version has a different, more efficient execution plan.

Comment: Also, what's the point of using a left join in that at all?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I am already discussing with IT about upgrading SQLite by recompiling and going through that process. That would be ideal.

Comment: I used `SELECT *` and a very basic join just to illustrate the issue in a simple manner. As a side note I find 'Show Columns' plus Excel very useful for picking which fields I want. I need left join for multiple reasons, including assigning incrementing sequence numbers (in the absence of window functions in this old version of SQLite).
If I need to upgrade SQLite, that gives more weight to my argument to IT to do so.